# Skip length check for a specified $_POST

Tags: php

I'm checking if each POST's length is above 5.

```
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    if (strlen($val) < 5) {
        $go= true;
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I skip one perticualr POST from being checked for a lengh of above 5.

Basically I need to check all POST's are above 5 in length but I want it to ignore checking `$_POST['Yes'];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `continue`

```
if($val == $_POST['Yes']) continue;
```

This will skip the counting of `$_POST['Yes']`.

Thus, your code should be like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $val) {
    if($val == $_POST['Yes']) continue;
    if (strlen($val) < 5) {
        $go= true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should that go within the if statement or just below the `foreach()`?

Comment: It should be after your `foreach ` statement

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @Becky Updated code, I forgot to equate it initially, it should work now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is not actually correct, as you are comparing the value.
It will fail, for example, on input:

```
$_POST = array('Yes'=>'a', 'SomethingElse'=>'a');
```

This will ignore $_POST['SomethingElse'] even though it should not.

**Correct Solution:**

To find the solution correctly, you should also loop over the keys:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) {
  if ($key === 'Yes')
    continue;
  if (strlen($val) < 5) {
    $go= true;
    break;
  }
}
```

**Multiple Values:**

If you want to do this for multiple keys, you can store them in an array:

```
$ignores = array('Yes',);
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) {
  if (in_array($key, $ignores))
    continue;
  if (strlen($val) < 5) {
    $go= true;
    break;
  }
}
```